# Access custom right click filter menus

Tags: vba, ms-access, menu

I want to create custom right click filter menus in Access. I got code that does that, it's below

here's the problem. obviously, a field can be text or numbers. the default Access menu deals with that by creating a group Number Filters or Text Filters.
But my filter doesn't have those groups, and, more importantly, doesn't look at the field type and doesn't hide irrelevant menus like the native one does. In the native one, it seems that they look at the field type, and, based on that, show TEXT FILTERS or NUMBER FILTERS

how do i do that without doing horrible things like program OnClick of every control and reload the menu based on the field type?
like, is there a way to mimic what Access does? Hide irrelevant menus or show a different group based on field type

[image]

```
    Public Sub sbFormsShortcutMenu()

Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next

CommandBars("MainRightClick").Delete
Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("MainRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True) 'NEW COMMANDBAR
 
With cmbRightClick
    
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True) ' Cut
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19, , , True) ' Copy
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 22, , , True) ' Paste 
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True) 'Sort AZ 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 211, , , True) 'Sort ZA 10068
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True) 'FilterEqualsSelection 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10071, , , True) 'FilterNotEqualsSelection 10071
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10090, , , True) 'FilterBeginsWithSelection 10090
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12265, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotBeginsWithSelection 12265
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10076, , , True) 'FilterContainsSelection 10076
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10089, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotContainSelection 10089
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10091, , , True) 'FilterEndsWithSelection 10091
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12266, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotEndWithSelection 12266 
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10095, , , True) 'FilterSmallerThanSelection 10095
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10094, , , True) 'FilterLargerThanSelection 10094
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10062, , , True) 'FilterBetween 10062 
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True) 'FilterBySelection 640
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 3017, , , True) 'FilterExcludingSelection 3017

End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't reloading the menu based on field type be mimicking Access native behavior? So how do you call this sub?

Comment: Then I'd have to program every control. Really hoping to avoid that, was hoping there's another way. Why does access look at the field type with their menus but once I'm using their MSO it no longer does that. I'm using their buttons, not like I wrote them myself. Why would it stop?

Comment: Actually, it still looks at the field type because it hides those that don't apply. I just don't understand how to mimic showing different menus based on field type. Or, best option, hide irrelevant ones

Comment: I vote for programming event for each field but using the same function for all just sending the field type as function parameter
e.g.: 
make new function RClick(fieldType as int)
in event procedure for all controls use =RClick(1) for text  and =RClick(2) for number
In your RClick function you check for the field type value and build the proper menu. This is not much work and only one function is coded for all controls

Comment: Yep :) except that I was hoping for this to apply for all my apps. I have the main custom app which I start development with and it has a bunch of tools for stuff I use often. And this was supposed to be part of that. And when you think of it from that standpoint, it becomes an issue because each app will have different forms and controls. And that would've been OK since I can pull a list of forms and controls but then it becomes a mess :) not every control has to have these menus. Also, some controls will already have OnClick events and if I was to write code that would automatically write...

Comment: Ran out of space to write. And without automation, this option to me isn't appealing  too much work to implement in complex apps. But if this was for one app - I'd agree completely, program each box with 1 function.

Comment: Ignore previous comment, cant delete or edit it.  OnClick events for each, i'd run into issues. I dont know of a way to reliably get list of all subs and edit them. Adding a sub - no problem. Editing - have to play around with it some more. Also, afraid this will slow down apps. Guess, need to try to implement this and see how it works out

Comment: @mamadsp hey, ended up programming every control, not so bad after all, thank you for the push!

Comment: @lalachka good job but too much code. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the following code**

```
Public Function sbFormsShortcutMenu()  'Make it function not sub

    Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
    Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

    On Error Resume Next

    CommandBars("MainRightClick").Delete
    Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("MainRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True) 'NEW COMMANDBAR

    With cmbRightClick

        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True) ' Cut
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19, , , True) ' Copy
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 22, , , True) ' Paste'
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True) 'Sort AZ 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 211, , , True) 'Sort ZA 10068
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True) 'FilterEqualsSelection 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10071, , , True) 'FilterNotEqualsSelection 10071
        If IsNumeric(Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl) then  'Check if numeric add numeric options and if not add text options
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10095, , , True) 'FilterSmallerThanSelection 10095
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10094, , , True) 'FilterLargerThanSelection 10094
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10062, , , True) 'FilterBetween 10062
        Else
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10076, , , True) 'FilterContainsSelection 10076
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10089, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotContainSelection 10089                
        End If
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True) 'FilterBySelection 640
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 3017, , , True) 'FilterExcludingSelection 3017

    End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Then use ***=sbFormsShortcutMenu()*** in each "On Mouse Down" event of your controls on the form.
This would make the solution general for any form and any control on it for Numeric and Text type controls.
Of course you could extend it more to check for Date type controls as well and update the menu accordingly **:)**

Edit: **It is not working correctly if the form is used as subform.**

Comment: duh lol, i got so caught up in automating the rest of it (scanning every form, adding OnMouse code automatically, etc) that i totally missed this one. thank you! and why make it a function? just wondering, it's not returning anything

Comment: hmm, you have the Me.ActiveControl, that won't work, will still need to add more code to pull the form name and add it to each sub. and then i guess might as well kept as is? or am i missing something?

Comment: maybe the function will request the name of the form and the name of the form is passed to it at run time from the control. the code will be 2 lines shorter for each control, not that bad. it's written automatically anyway, so it's not like i had to write all that. but still, the shorter the better

Comment: You are correct about Me.ActiveControl instead I should have used Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl. I will modify it to the code to keep correct reference.

Comment: lol i already wrote this convoluted thingie that gets the subforms, will test and see if this will work instead. thank you!

Comment: I don't see why you need to add any code to controls. It is only in the OnClick property you set it to   =sbFormsShortcutMenu()   so you don't need to have separate function for each control !! If this point is not clear I can send sample database with the solution.

Comment: Adding a function to be able to set it as property value for OnClick. If it is a sub it will not work. That is all.

Comment: I will test it first, and if I still don't get it, I will ask for a sample. Thank you very much!! On another note, I'm now having issues with ribbons. Are you good with those too? Will post a question shortly

Comment: for text all is well, but for numbers - doesnt seem like it's recognizing something. less than and more than are both greyed out. also, i was wondering, access has a few more menus for numbers, like, less than, more than... but i cant get those to work, only less than or equals to and greater than or equals to.

Comment: You are welcome.I don't like using ribbons in my modules as they contain some inevitable menus that can give undesired results or even exploit the code. Long ago I implemented my own classic menu simulator and my own menu builder to build custom menus and using it in all my modules that need menus. I will review you question any way (at least to learn).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247196/discussion-between-lalachka-and-mamadsp).

Comment: Sample database link   
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19nzz0nxr--b14W1m88KWCSkloZNdqtGi/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I ended up programming every control. I created 2 versions of the above code, here they go

```
Public Sub sbFormsShortcutMenuNumber()

Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next

CommandBars("MainRightClick").Delete
Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("MainRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True) 'NEW COMMANDBAR
 
With cmbRightClick
    
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True) ' Cut
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19, , , True) ' Copy
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 22, , , True) ' Paste'
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True) 'Sort AZ 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 211, , , True) 'Sort ZA 10068
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True) 'FilterEqualsSelection 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10071, , , True) 'FilterNotEqualsSelection 10071
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10095, , , True) 'FilterSmallerThanSelection 10095
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10094, , , True) 'FilterLargerThanSelection 10094
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10062, , , True) 'FilterBetween 10062
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True) 'FilterBySelection 640
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 3017, , , True) 'FilterExcludingSelection 3017

End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
        
End Sub

Public Sub sbFormsShortcutMenuText()

Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next

CommandBars("MainRightClick").Delete
Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("MainRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True) 'NEW COMMANDBAR
 
With cmbRightClick
    
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True) ' Cut
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19, , , True) ' Copy
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 22, , , True) ' Paste'
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True) 'Sort AZ 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 211, , , True) 'Sort ZA 10068
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True) 'FilterEqualsSelection 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10071, , , True) 'FilterNotEqualsSelection 10071
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10076, , , True) 'FilterContainsSelection 10076
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10089, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotContainSelection 10089
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True) 'FilterBySelection 640
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 3017, , , True) 'FilterExcludingSelection 3017

End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

In case someone is wondering, so far, doesn't seem like performance is affected. on the first right-click when first opening the app - there's a slight lag but after that - instant. But I haven't tested it with the backend being on the server, my backend is on my local drive.

Here's the code used for each control.
So, every form where you want this done has to have the Shortcut Menu set to whatever you named your shortcut bar (in my case it's "MainRightClick") and this can be automated (create a sub that loops through all forms, opens each in design view and sets the shortcut menu to your menu)

To get it to show up in the dropdowns in the Shortcut Menu option in the form - run the above code. It only has to be run once and it will remember it forever. I still have some old test menus saved somewhere somehow which I cant get rid of. No big deal, they just annoy me showing up in the dropdown in design mode :)

Anyway, and then, for each control do this

```
Private Sub FirstName_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = acRightButton Then
        If IsNumeric(Me.FirstName) Then
            sbFormsShortcutMenuNumber
            Else
            sbFormsShortcutMenuText
        End If
    End If End Sub
```

I automated this entire process so that I can do this for all my apps and it's not so bad after all

Comment: Great @lalachka. Check my answer. it would give more general and much smaller code (I reused your code with some modifications)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
never mind. this works for regular forms but not with subforms. i'm in the process of trying to figure out if there's a way to easily get parents of a sub but i have a feeling i will be right back where i started: extra lines of code for every MouseDown event

making a change to the @mamadsp answer above
The problem is that me. can't be called in a function. this code isnt tested but should work
so...

```
Public Function fnFormsShortcutMenu(vrFormName as string, vrFieldName as string)  

    Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
    Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

    On Error Resume Next

    CommandBars("MainRightClick").Delete
    Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("MainRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True) 'NEW COMMANDBAR

    With cmbRightClick

        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True) ' Cut
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19, , , True) ' Copy
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 22, , , True) ' Paste'
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True) 'Sort AZ 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 211, , , True) 'Sort ZA 10068
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True) 'FilterEqualsSelection 10068
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10071, , , True) 'FilterNotEqualsSelection 10071
        If IsNumeric(forms(vrFormName)(vrFieldName)) then  'Check if numeric add numeric options and if not add text options
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10095, , , True) 'FilterSmallerThanSelection 10095
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10094, , , True) 'FilterLargerThanSelection 10094
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10062, , , True) 'FilterBetween 10062
        Else
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10076, , , True) 'FilterContainsSelection 10076
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10089, , , True) 'FilterDoesNotContainSelection 10089                
        End If
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True) 'FilterBySelection 640
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 3017, , , True) 'FilterExcludingSelection 3017

    End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

and then each control gets this

```
Private Sub FirstName_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
        If Button = acRightButton Then
             fnFormsShortcutMenuNumber(me.Name, me.ActiveControl.name)
        End If 
End Sub
```